Calculating partial pressures of real gases in a ternary mixture
I need some help on how to calculate the partial pressures of a ternary mixture using the Peng-Robinson equation of state (PR-EOS) instead of the ideal gas law.
I need to prepare a mixture of three gases i.e., O2, N2 and CO2 through sequential filling and inside a closed volume, for example a pressure vessel. If I use the ideal gas law then I can calculate the partial pressures of each component as the product of the mole fraction $(x_{i})$ of the component with the total pressure $(P)$,
$$p_{i} \equiv x_{i}P$$
The PR-EOS will provide a more accurate description of the real gas,
$$p=\frac{R_{0}T}{v_{m}-b}-\frac{a\alpha}{v_{m}^{2}+2bv_{m}-b^2}$$
where $p$ is the pressure, $v_{m}$ is the specific molar volume, $T$ is the temperature, $a$ is the cohesion pressure and $b$ is the co-volume. The values of $a$ and $b$ are calculated from the equations below,
$$a = \frac{0.457235R_{0}^{2}T_{c}^2}{p_{c}}$$
$$b = \frac{0.077796R_{0}T_{c}}{p_{c}}$$
where $R_{0} = 0.008314472 \mathrm{\frac{L\cdot MPa}{K\cdot mol}}$ is the gas constant, $T_{c}$ the critical temperature and $p_{c}$ the critical pressure. The factor $\alpha$ is a function of the acentric factor $\omega$ and the reduced temperature $T_{r} = T/T_{c}$,
$$a= \left[ 1+(0.37464 + 1.54226\omega-0.26992\omega^{2})(1-\sqrt{T_{r}}) \right]^{2}$$
The thermodynamic parameters for O2, N2 and CO2 are:

O2: $p_{c}=5.043 \mathrm{MPa}$, $T_{c} = 154.58 \mathrm{K}$, $\omega = 0.0222$
N2: $p_{c}=3.3958 \mathrm{MPa}$, $T_{c} = 126.19 \mathrm{K}$, $\omega = 0.0372$
CO2: $p_{c}=7.3773 \mathrm{MPa}$, $T_{c} = 304.13 \mathrm{K}$, $\omega = 0.22394$

The required mixture needs to have a composition of 10/20/70%mol O2/N2/CO2 with a final pressure of the mixture $1\mathrm{MPa}$ at $20^{\mathrm{o}}\mathrm{C}$. In the sequential filling we start with compound with the lowest mol% (O2 in this case) then the next lower (N2) and finally we top with the compound with the highest concentration (CO2).
My questions:

I start with O2: It is quite straight forward to calculate the $a$, $\alpha$ and $b$. When it comes to the equation of $p$ how do I indetify $v_{m}$?
How do I carry on with the next two mixture components i.e., N2 and CO2?


Note: your stated compositions add up to more than 100%.

Thank you @DavidWhite. I missed that.
